# Unable to retrieve time along with date to fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar (v2) loaded with all events created in mysql. But when I click on an event, the time is showing as `00:00:00` for  `start`  and `null` for `end`  even if I have both start and end time set in mysql. I guess this is also forcing all events stay as `allDay` event.

Please advise.

Below attaching screenshots from mysql and script I am using to retrive values from an event to boostrap modal.

MySQL table screenshot
[image: MySQL table screenshot]

js Code :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2015-12-16, 00:00:00',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: "events.php",
                eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 1) {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
                eventClick: function (event) {
                    $('#eventTitle').val(event.title);
                    $('#eventStart').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#eventEnd').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#eventDescription').val(event.description);
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }
```

I am using a simple `select` statement to retrieve data from mysql.

events.php

```
<?php
// List of events
 $json = array();

 // Query that retrieves events
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id";

 // connection to the database
 try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', '');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
  exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }
 // Execute the query
 $resultat = $bdd->query($sql) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

 // sending the encoded result to success page
 echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while but found a solution/workaround.

1) Instead of declaring the startdate & enddate columns in MySQL as DATETIME, its better works in VARCHAR format.

I tried below method to store the date & time including timezone.

```
var startdate = moment($('#eventStart').val()).format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS")+05:30 \\string concatenated with timezone
var enddate = moment($('#eventEnd').val()).format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS")+05:30 \\string concatenated with timezone
```

The format required for the fullcalendar to load events during page load should be like the one below for events other than allDay,

```
[{"id":"1","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-14T00:01:00+05:30","end":"2015-01-14T00:01:00+05:30","allDay":false}]
```

Credit : Ashik Basheer

I am newbee to programming, so any suggestions / recommendations are most welcome to improve the code.